# Using Soil Line to Assess Soil Fertility?

Tags: line, soil

I am using a Soil Line model to research possible soil fertility in bare soil patches in southern Africa. I am using a function in R called BSL (Bare soil line) to create the soil line from some satellite image: function is at https://rdrr.io/cran/landsat/man/BSL.html. The Soil Line plots NIR and Red reflectance values from a satellite image.

If I am just generating the soil lines to compare the soil lines' slope and  intercept values to estimate soil organic matter, do I need to analyze the vegetation pixel values as well?

I have included the R-generated Soil line graph as an example:

[image: Soil Line example from R package]

I am new to studying soils so but I have read much of the pertinent literature, such as these ones:

> A.R. Huete, A Soil Adjusted Vegetation Index (1988)
>
> Baret, F., Jacquemoud, S., & Hanocq, J. F. About the Soil Line
>   Concept in Remote (1993)
>
> Ahmadian et. al. A New Concept of Soil Line Retrieval from Landsat 8
>   Images for Estimating Plant Biophysical Parameters (2016).